# How do I get the thumbnail hover to change the image above?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am trying to get the thumbnails on my page to change the image above them when you hover over it with the mouse.
I'm very new to javascript, and can't seem to get my head around what to do here. 
I have already used fancybox so that when you click on the larger image it opens a gallery.

I have included the html and css below. If anyone could help me with the javascript I would really appreciate it.

```
 <html lang="en">
 <head> 
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
   <meta name="description" content="Collectables and memorabilia from the  TV show LOST. Screen used props, action figures, trading cards, costumes and much much more">
   <meta name="keywords" content="autographs, props, trading cards, Mcfarlane, Bif Bang Pow, ABC, LOST, RITTENHOUSE, Inkworks, Damon Lindelof, Carlton Cuse, Oceanic 815, Ajira 316, 4815162342
                                 authentic, screen used, dharma initiative, kahana, hawaii, beach, jungle,the others, french science expedition, Jack, Charlie, Kate, Hurley, Jacob, MIB">
   <meta charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <div class= <title>LOST Collector</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>

   <!-- Add jQuery library -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

 <!-- Add fancyBox -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5"   type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

 <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="pagecontent">
        <header>    
            <a href="http://www.lostcollector.com">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Lost Collector" title="Lost Collector"/>
            </a> 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About LOST Collector</a></li>
                    <li><a   href="mailto:lostcollector815@gmail.com">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <ul id="navigation_layout">
            <li><a href="artwork.html" id="artworknav">Artwork</a></li>
            <li><a href="autographs.html" id="autographsnav">Autographs</a>     </li>
            <li><a href="badgespins.html">Badges and Pins</a></li>
            <li><a href="booksandmagazines.html">Books/Magazines</a></li>
            <li><a href="clothing.html">Clothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="dvdsandcds.html">Dvds and Cds</a></li>
            <li><a href="filmcrew.html">Film Crew</a></li>
            <li><a href="originalprops.html">Original Props</a></li>
            <li><a href="specialevents.html">Special Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="toysandgames.html">Toys and games</a></li>
            <li><a href="tradingcards.html">Trading cards</a></li>
            <li><a href="everythingelse.html">Everything else</a></li>
            <div class="noline">
               <li><a href="wishlist.html">Wish list</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul> 
        <div class="itemdetails">
           <div class="itemtext">
                <h1>Inkworks: Season One</h1>
                <h2>AR-1 unused Redemption Card</h2>
                <h3>For Maggie Grace autograph card A-3</h3>
                <p>Inkworks included redemption cards for the first 3 autograph cards in the packs because they didn't receive the signed cards back in time to include them in the boxes. So the redemption cards were issued instead. The idea was when you found the card you filled it out and sent it to Inkworks who would then send you back the punched redemption card and the autograph card in question. 
                </p>
           </div>

           <div class="itemdetails_aside">
                <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/AR1big.jpg"><img src="images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/AR1.jpg" alt="AR-1 Redemption Card" title="click to enlarge" height="430" width="308"/>
           </div>
           <div class="thumbnails">
                <img src="images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/thumbnails/ar1.jpg" alt="ar1" title="Click thumbnail to enlarge" width="107" height="150" /></a>
                <img src="images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/thumbnails/ar1mgb.jpg" alt="mgrdmp" title="Click thumbnail to enlarge" width="107" height="150" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
 </body>
```

```
body {
background-color: #5D6D7E;
display: inline;
}

/*Styles body background colour, text colour and font syle and size*/
div.pagecontent {
margin: 10px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
border-radius: 20px;
width: 1300px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 90%;
}

/*Styles the header*/
header {
width: 1300px;
height: 200px;
background: #ffffff;
position: static;

border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
margin-top: 0;
}

/*finds all img tags as links inside header*/
header a img {
padding-bottom:  10px;
margin: 25px 10px 10px 20px;
display: inline;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
}


nav {
display: inline;
float: right;
}

nav ul li  {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;
padding: 40px 10px 30px;
margin-top: 25px;     
margin-right: 25px;
}     

nav li a {
display: inline-block;
padding: 60px 10px 30px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 90%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;
} 

nav li a:hover {
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #000000;
}

/*selects the navigation_layout id, styles the whole nav layout*/
#navigation_layout  {
position: absolute;
width: 1300px;
top: 188px;
float: left;
list-style: none; 
background-color:  #ffffff;
border-top:  #ffffff;
padding: 0;
}

 /*makes the nav list items display from the left*/
 #navigation_layout li {
 float: left;
 background-color: #000000;
 margin: 1px;
 padding-right: 2.65px;
 list-style: none;     
 }

 /*styles the list a tags*/
#navigation_layout li a  {
display: block;
padding: 4px 9px 4px 8px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 90%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #ffffff; 
}

 /*styles link colour when mouse hovers over it only**/
    #navigation_layout li a:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    }   


div.pic img{ padding:2px;
         border: 1px solid #000000;         
}

div.itemdetails {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width:1250px;
height: auto;
margin: 25px;
border: 1px solid  #000000;
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

/**div.itemtext is all of the text on the page, with separate rules**/        
div.itemtext {
float: right;
width: 600px;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}
div.itemtext h1 {
float:right;
width:600px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 300%;
}

div.itemtext h2 {
float: right;
width: 600px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
font-size: 200%;
}

div.itemtext h3{
font-size: 200%;
}

div.itemtext p{
float: right;
width: 600px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 200%;
margin-top: 0;
}


div.itemdetails_aside {
display: block;
float: left;
padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
margin: 25px;
}

div.itemdetails_aside img {
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
background-color: #ffffff
}





div.itemdetails_content {
float: right;
width: 550px;
height: auto;
padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
margin:25px;
}

div.thumbnails {
display: inline;
float:left;
padding: 25px 25px 25px;
}

div.thumbnails img{
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #000000;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
margin: 10px;
}




div.related_items{
display: inline;
padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
margin-right: 100px;
margin-left: 100px;
}


div.box {
margin: auto;
width:1150px;
height: 400px;
}

div.gallery {
width: 1100px;
height: 900px;
margin: auto;
}
div.cardcontent {
display: inline;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
}

 div.cardcontent img{
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: `<a class="fancybox"`... is missing the closing `</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your images follow this pattern of naming..

```
ar1.jpg (thumbnail)    
ar1big.jpg (full size)
```

Either add a new attribute to the thumbnail tags, say `rn=""` (**r**oot**n**ame) or make sure the `alt=""` have the root image name (excluding .jpg) then you can just add the word big to the root to link to the large, full size images when moused over.

**jquery**

```
$(function() { // document ready
    $('.thumbnails img').mouseover(function() { // when thumb hovered do..
        var fullImagePath = 'images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/'; // root path to full size image
        var imageRootName = $(this).attr('rn'); // get root image name
        var bigImageNameAndPath = fullImagePath + imageRootName + 'big' + '.jpg'; // put it all together
        $('.fancybox img').attr('src', bigImageNameAndPath); // replace src="" with path to full image corresponding to thumb hovered
    });
});
```

The above is untested, let me know if you have problems with it.

**html**

```
<div class="itemdetails_aside">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/ar1big.jpg">
        <img src="images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/AR1.jpg" alt="AR-1 Redemption Card" title="click to enlarge" height="430" width="308"/>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="thumbnails">
    <img src="images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/thumbnails/ar1.jpg" rn="ar1" alt="ar1" title="Click thumbnail to enlarge" width="107" height="150" />
    <img src="images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/thumbnails/ar1mgb.jpg" rn="ar1mgb" alt="mgrdmp" title="Click thumbnail to enlarge" width="107" height="150" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks very much mate, that seems to be working great. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ID and Classes for img elements like this :

```
  <div class="itemdetails_aside">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/tradingcards/season1inkworks/AR1big.jpg">
        <img id="imgBigThumb" src="1.jpg" alt="AR-1 Redemption Card" title="click to enlarge" height="430" width="308" />
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails">
        <img class="imgSmallThumb" src="1.jpg" alt="ar1" title="Click thumbnail to enlarge" width="107" height="150" /></a>
        <img class="imgSmallThumb" src="2.jpg" alt="mgrdmp" title="Click thumbnail to enlarge" width="107" height="150" /></a>
  </div>
```

Then javascript code is not very difficult :

```
var BigThumb = document.getElementById("imgBigThumb"),
    SmallThumbs = document.getElementsByClassName("imgSmallThumb");

for(var i=0; i<SmallThumbs.length;i++) {
    (function(i){
        SmallThumbs[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
            BigThumb.setAttribute("src",SmallThumbs[i].getAttribute("src"));
        });
    }(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) may be what you are looking for. See Hover Effect at the bottom of the linked page. No Javascript needed.